# Replace Vector Data in a Data Frame that doesn't match criteria

Tags: r, replace, gsub, grepl

I have a data frame:

```
Bldg    Bldg-Room   Expt. #
Bldg 5A NA  NA
NA  5A-141  vacant
Reynolds    5A-142  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00756
Reynolds    5A-143  S00168
NA  NA  S00756
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  5A-144  vacant
NA  5A-145  vacant
Reynolds    5A-146  7590.21
NA  5A-147  vacant
Reynolds    5A-148  7712.01
NA  NA  7712.01
NA  NA  7712.01
Lewis   5A-149  occupied
Lewis   5A-150  occupied
```

[image]

In df$Bldg (1st column) I want to replace any text string that doesn't contain "Bldg*" with NA

I have tried grep, grepl, and gsub but not sure I am putting in correct parameters.

desired out put would be:

```
Bldg    Bldg-Room   Expt. #
Bldg 5A NA  NA
NA  5A-141  vacant
NA  5A-142  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00756
NA  5A-143  S00168
NA  NA  S00756
NA  NA  S00168
NA  NA  S00168
NA  5A-144  vacant
NA  5A-145  vacant
NA  5A-146  7590.21
NA  5A-147  vacant
NA  5A-148  7712.01
NA  NA  7712.01
NA  NA  7712.01
NA  5A-149  occupied
NA  5A-150  occupied
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for something like: `df[!grepl("Bldg", df$Bldg), "Bldg"] <- NA`?

Comment: you may also use `stringr::str_detect` in combination with `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

We can do it with `grepl` and negation:

```
df$Bldg[!grepl("\\bBldg\\b", df$Bldg)] <- NA
```

Result:

```
df
      Bldg
1  Bldg 5A
2     <NA>
3 Bldg 10B
4     <NA>
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Bldg = c("Bldg 5A", NA, "Bldg 10B", "Someothertext")
)
```